# Splitting a number string in pandas / python

Tags: python

I am looking to split the following column to two columns in my pandas dataframe by splitting on the last 0 in every row.

```
000012345
000012345
000012345
```

What I would like it to look like

```
0000 12345
0000 12345
```

I've been looking into str.split from can't seem to figure how to approach this as there is no usual delimiter, and I can not figure out how to make it split on the 4th 0.

I have had success with a similar issue previously with the following command, but can not seem to figure it out, as im not looking to split labels, but values in the rows.

df.labels.str.split(':',1).tolist()

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "col" the column, you can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a lookbehind regex:

```
df['col'].str.split(r'(?<=^.{4})', expand=True)
```

regex:

```
(?<=^.{4})    # match the empty space preceded by the first 4 characters
```

Or use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['col'].str.extract('(^.{4})(.*)')
# df[['col2', 'col3']] = df['col'].str.extract('(^.{4})(.*)')
```

Full example:

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df['col'].str.split('(?<=^.{4})', expand=True)
```

output:

```
         col  col2   col3
0  000012345  0000  12345
1  000012345  0000  12345
2  000012345  0000  12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code using **string replace**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['000012345','000012345','000012345']})

df['col2'] =  df['col1'].astype(int)

df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'].replace(str(row['col2']),''), axis =1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col1   col2  col3
0  000012345  12345  0000
1  000012345  12345  0000
2  000012345  12345  0000
```